# Drag a feature POLYGON OL3

Tags: openlayers-3

I try to find code to drag a polygon (not modify)....OL3

polygon is created by code (bbox for print area).

can anybody shere code?

```
    var format = new ol.format.WKT();
    var feature = format.readFeature(wkt2);

    selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({style: styles});
    map.addInteraction(selectInteraction);
    selectInteraction.getFeatures().push(feature);
    modifyInteraction = new ol.interaction.DragAndDrop({
        features: selectInteraction.getFeatures()
    });
    map.addInteraction(modifyInteraction);


    vector = new ol.layer.Vector({ 
        style: styles,
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [feature]
        })
    });
    map.getLayers().insertAt(1000, vector);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extension called [Transform Interaction](http://viglino.github.io/ol3-ext/examples/map.interaction.transform.html) work fine with dragging. It also has support for rotating, stretching and scaling. It is definitely worth a look!

Answer (score 3):

See the drag features example here: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/examples/drag-features.html

Also there is work in progress on a Translate interaction see: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3250